# Remove wrong PATH from my environment

Tags: linux, bash

I was installing Swift on my Linux Mint 17 Qiana and while writing a path to it I made an error: instead of writing

```
$ export PATH=/home/alex/swift/usr/bin/:"${PATH}"
```

I wrote

```
$ export PATH=/home/alex/swift/usr/bin/:"#{PATH}"
```

and now, when I run

```
$ echo $PATH
```

it returns me the following:

```
/home/alex/swift/usr/bin/:/home/alex/swift/usr/bin/:#{PATH}
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Exit the terminal and it will be unset

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Thank you! Please, post it as an answer so that I could accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set PATH on your Shell's environment just exiting the terminal session will reset it.

Answer (score 1):

Just run: `export PATH=<path_without_whatever_you_want_removed>`

That will set `$PATH` to only that, the rest of the `PATH` will be lost.

Comment: ... Which is pretty useless.

Comment: @tripleee how is it useless? It sets the path to that!

Comment: Which loses all the standard paths, and specifies a single custom path twice. Unlikely to solve any problem for the OP, and could turn up desperation a notch if you don't know how easy the proper fix is, and your system seems hosed because none of the regular commands work any longer. The first comment to the question is much more helpful.

Comment: @tripleee You don't lose "standard path". The OP has to just copy paste Whatever appears when he does `echo $PATH` just without the unwanted part. And the PATH variable will have only whatever was exported.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you had updated your answer. It's not quite so useless any more, but unless the OP has a record of the original and knows which parts to keep, this is still not directly helpful.

Comment: @tripleee The earlier answer was also correct. It was just using the value from the OP's `echo $PATH` output(shown in the question).